# Holding events in Vaadin

Tags: java, events, vaadin

I have the following issue. Say, user can click on some UI component. Each click requires a lot of calculations and changes other UI components significantly, so it's extremely expensive. Order of clicks is not important.

So it would be cool to hold event during some time, and only if there are no other events during that time, send it to server. Otherwise all events except the last one should be ignored.

Is there a way to implement such a behaviour in Vaadin?

Best regards, Dmitriy.

Answer (score 1):

Your application runs in a single session.  Given that it's not all UI components that trigger the expensive recalculation, you can associate a listener with your event. Store a copy of the event, and start a timer thread.  If a new request comes in, flush the previous value.  The key element here is that you must start a thread, otherwise your UI will hang.

Answer (score 0):

To complement the other answer. There is a thread example in the book of vaadin for the progress indicator. This shows how to keep the UI responsive and take a thread to handle the events. You can create a thread that contains a timer and receives messages from the event threads . The timer thread will then respond according to the restrictions you implement.
Check the progress bar code for the a thread example in vaadin:

https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.progressbar.html